# Invalid Authentication method, invalid client error when trying to connect with OIDC

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid-connect

We're trying to develop an ASP Net application, and we have to use an oidc authentication system.

we've got our own OIDC server. When we try to connect we've got an error message :

*"System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'Invalid authentication method for accessing this endpoint.', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'."*

here is our ConfigureService function and Configure function:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddOptions();
            SetGlobalConfig();
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddResponseCompression(options => 
            {
                options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
                options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
                options.EnableForHttps = true;                
            });
            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-OurAppli";
                options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-OurAppli";
                options.FormFieldName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-OurAppli";                
            });
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;                
            });
            
            services.AddDetection();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            
            var identityUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityUrl");
            var bearerUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("BearerUrl");
            var callBackUrl = Configuration.GetValue<string>("CallBackUrl");
            var sessionCookieLifetime = Configuration.GetValue("SessionCookieLifetimeMinutes", 60);

            
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                
            })
                .AddCookie(setup => setup.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionCookieLifetime))
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                    
                    options.ClientId = "*******";
                    options.ClientSecret = "********";
                    
                    options.Authority = "https://ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServerwebsso/oauth2/multiauth";
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                   
                  
                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid uid isMemberOf");
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Configuration = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                    {
                        AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServerwebsso/oauth2/multiauth/authorize",
                        TokenEndpoint = "https://ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServerwebsso/oauth2/multiauth/access_token",
                        UserInfoEndpoint = "https://ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServerwebsso/oauth2/multiauth/userinfo",
                        EndSessionEndpoint = "https://ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServerwebsso/oauth2/multiauth/connect/endSession",
                        RegistrationEndpoint = "https://ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServer/oauth2/multiauth/connect/register",
                        JwksUri = "ourOIDCServer/ourOIDCServer/oauth2/multiauth/connect/jwk_uri",
                        
                    };
                    
                    
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                        {
                             context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("acr_values","ourACR");
                             context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("authlevel", "3");

                            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(options.ClientId + ":" + options.ClientSecret);
                            context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Post " + byteArray);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    };
                    

                });
            
           
            services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            });
           
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseResponseCompression();
           app.UseDetection();
           app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; font-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'");

                await next();
            });
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Index",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });
             app.UseStaticFiles();
            
           


        }`
```

And there is our HomeController :

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_user);
            Console.WriteLine(_habilitation);
            dynamic models = new ExpandoObject();
            models.detection = _detectionService;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_user) || _user != "")
            {
                models.Authorization = _habilitation;
                models.Name = _user;
                Console.WriteLine(models.Name + "    Auth= " + models.Authorization);
                models.Habilitation = 1;
            }

               
            return View("Index", models);
        }
```

I never used an OIDC authentication system with ASP Net so i don't know if there is something wrong with my code...

Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add to the question how the client is defined? What OIDC provider are you using?

The problem seems that the client asks for "authorization code flow" here:

```
options.ResponseType = "code";
```

but the OIDC provider does not have that enabled. I would check that first.